# How to change a member field with Kotlin reflection?

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I'm porting a class from Java to Kotlin. This class declares hundreds of objects. Each object has a name property which is identical with the declared variable name of the object. Java reflection allows to use the declared name via reflection to set the object member `name`. Just saves one parameter in hundreds of constructors.

I try to do the same in Kotlin but can't figure out how to do the property setting. Here is some simplified test code:

```
import kotlin.reflect.full.companionObject
import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMemberProperties

class MyTestObject() {

    var name: String = "NotInitialized"

    companion object {
        val Anton = MyTestObject()
        val Berta = MyTestObject()
        val Caesar = MyTestObject()
    }
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    println(MyTestObject.Anton.name) // name not yet initialized

    // Initialize 'name' with the variable name of the object:
    for (member in MyTestObject::class.companionObject!!.declaredMemberProperties) {
        if (member.returnType.toString() == "myPackage.MyTestObject") {
            println("$member: ${member.name}")

            // Set 'name' property to 'member.name':
            // ???
        }
    }

    println(MyTestObject.Anton.name) // now with the initialized name
}
```

The `???` line is where I would like to get access to the `name` property of `MyTestObject` to set it to to `member.name`. I'm looking for a function similar to `(member.toObject() as MyTestObject).name = member.name`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While `kotlin-reflection` strives to be type-safe, sometimes the type system and the inference logic are not enough to allow for the things like what you are trying to do in a type-safe way. So, you have to make unchecked casts, stating that your knowledge about the types is more than the compiler can infer.

In your case, it's enough to cast `member` so that you can pass the companion object instance into its `.get(...)` and use the result as a `MyTestObject`, replace the `// ???` line with:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
(member as KProperty1<Any, MyTestObject>)
    .get(MyTestObject::class.companionObject!!.objectInstance!!)
    .name = member.name
```

If you can replace `MyTestObject::class.companionObject!!` with `MyTestObject.Companion::class` (i.e. your actual use case does not involve getting `.companionObject` from different classes), the unchecked cast is not needed, and you can replace the statement above with this:

```
(member.get(MyTestObject.Companion) as MyTestObject).name = member.name
```

---

As an alternative that does not require companion object reflection at all, you can do the same binding logic with the delegation. [Implementing `provideDelegate`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#providing-a-delegate-since-11) allows you to customize the logic of initializing the property, and that's where you can assign the names:

```
operator fun MyTestObject.provideDelegate(
    thisRef: MyTestObject.Companion, 
    property: KProperty<*>
) = apply { name = property.name }

operator fun MyTestObject.getValue(
    thisRef: MyTestObject.Companion, 
    property: KProperty<*>
) = this
```

Then declare your properties as

```
val Anton by MyTestObject()
val Berta by MyTestObject()
val Caesar by MyTestObject()
```

Comment: Your first example worked. I tried your second one in the same class MyTestObject but the get() always delivers null. Have not tried the delegate example because I'm not familiar with this approach and it tends to make the software overly complex and unreadable.

Comment: The second example works if I move the code inside the companion object as init code after the property declarations. This looks like a simple and readable solution. Thank you for providing this solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final test code based on hotkey's solution:

```
package myPackage

import kotlin.reflect.full.declaredMemberProperties

class MyTestObject() {

  lateinit var name: String

  companion object {
    val Anton = MyTestObject()
    val Berta = MyTestObject()
    val Caesar = MyTestObject()

    init {
      for (member in MyTestObject.Companion::class.declaredMemberProperties) {
        if (member.returnType.toString() == "myPackage.MyTestObject") {
          (member.get(MyTestObject.Companion) as MyTestObject).name = member.name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
  println(MyTestObject.Anton.name)
  println(MyTestObject.Caesar.name)
}
```